# Population distribution in the problems of estimating the population proportion

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

In statistics there are many problems of estimating the population proportion.
For example, a typical problem of this type sounds like "estimate the percentage of smokers in the world population".

What is the population distribution in such problems?

Can we assume that it belongs to some parametric family?

Comment: Binomial, or some approximations of binomial distributions such as Poisson.

Comment: @Did Thanks! Now I understand why population proportion is usually denoted $p$ - because we can call it "success probability".

Comment: Just one clarification: I think it's more technically correct to say that population $(X_1, \ldots, X_N)$ has Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$, i.e. $X_i \sim \mathrm{Bern}(p)$. And **sum** of $X_1, \ldots, X_N$ has Binomial distribution $\mathrm{Bin}(N,p)$